# Jquery one issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

My mark up

```
<form action="blah/foo" method="POST" id="frm1">
<input type="hidden" id="v" />
</form>
......
......
<!--after some code-->
<button id="btn1">test</button>
<input type="text" id="somevalue" />
```

My purpose is when i click the button btn1,Grab the value of `somevalue` and give it to the hidden value `v` and submit the form ,the form needs to submit (ONLY ONCE) so i used the jquery `one` method and thats working fine

Second thing is if `somevalue` is empty i dont want to submit

THE PROBLEM scenario

```
<script>
$('#btn1').one('click',function(){
    if(!$('#somevalue').val()){
    $('p#msg').html('Empty value');
     return false;
    }
    $('#frm1').submit();

});
</script>
```

IF user first makes an empty input and try to submit the error msg will show..but after that even with a valid input the click event wont trigger(I know thats because of the `one` function)

Im looking for some alternative that the form will submit only once

Comment: you can create one function of yourself which allows user to click function only once based on the flags..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var form_sent = false;
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    if(form_sent == true){ return; }
    if(!$('#somevalue').val()){
        $('p#msg').html('Empty value');
        return false;
    }
    form_sent = true;
    $('#frm1').submit(); 
});
```

Comment: this seems intresting ill try

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using 'one' so that the your handler is called only once, declare your handler as a named function and use jQuery's bind / unbind to remove the click handler if (and only if) the field has a valid value when the form is submitted. Otherwise keep listening on the click event. As such:

```
function onFormSubmitted (e) {
    if($("#somevalue").val === "") { // If the field's value is invalid...
        $('p#msg').html('Empty value'); // ... then show error message...
        return; // ...and do nothing else - just keep on listening
    }

    // Ok, we have valid input so...
    $('#btn1').unbind("click", onFormSubmitted); // ...stop listening...
    $("#frm1").submit(); // ...and submit the form
}

// Start listening for the click event
$('#btn1').bind("click", onFormSubmitted);
```

Or, if you still want to use 'one' you can tweak the previous example, as such:

```
function onFormSubmitted (e) {
    if($("#somevalue").val === "") { // If the field's value is invalid...
        $('p#msg').html('Empty value'); // ... then show error message...
        $('#btn1').one("click", onFormSubmitted); // ...re-attach one-time listener...
        return; // ...and wait
    }

    // Ok, we have valid input so don't re-attach one-time listener...
    $("#frm1").submit(); // ...just submit the form
}

// Add one-time listener for the click event
$('#btn1').one("click", onFormSubmitted);
```

Comment: Fair enough - I added a very similar solution which uses the 'one' method.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('#btn1').one('click',function(){
    callFunc();
});

function callFunc(){
 if($('#somevalue').val() == ""){
    $('p#msg').html('Empty value');
    $('#btn1').one('click',function(){ callFunc(); });
    return false;
    }
 $('#frm1').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off why not have your input in the form?  Is there a specific reason to do it this way?

Also to do this in straight javascript rather than using jquery I would be doing something as follows:

```
<form action="blah/foo" method="POST" id="frm1" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

The validateForm just checks to see if the input is empty, if it is then it returns false, otherwise it returns true.  Returning false to onsubmit will stop the form submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Try bind event,

```
$('#btn1').bind('click',function(){
    if(!$('#somevalue').val()){
    $('p#msg').html('Empty value');
     return false;
    }
    $('#frm1').submit();

});​
```

Comment: But he wants the form to be submitted at most once.